# PostgreSQL 9.3: Check only time from timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, postgresql-9.3

I have the following table with one field of type `timestamp`.

```
Create table Test_Timestamp
(
    ColumnA timestamp
);
```

Now inserting some records for demonstration:

```
INSERT INTO Test_Timestamp VALUES('1900-01-01 01:21:15'),
                 ('1900-01-01 02:11:25'),
                 ('1900-01-01 12:52:10'),
                 ('1900-01-01 03:20:05');
```

Now I have created function `Function_Test` with two parameters namely `St_time` and `En_Time` which 
are of type varchar, In which I only pass the `time` like `00:00:01`. And after that Function has 
to return the table with that condition of two time's parameters.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Function_Test
(
    St_Time varchar,
    En_Time varchar
)

RETURNS TABLE
(
    columX timestamp
)
AS

$BODY$

Declare
    sql varchar;
    wher varchar;

BEGIN

    wher := 'Where columna BETWEEN '|| to_char(cast(St_Time as time),'''HH24:MI:SS''') ||' AND  '|| to_char(cast(En_Time as time),'''HH24:MI:SS''') ||'';

    RAISE INFO '%',wher;

    sql := 'SELECT * FROM Test_Timestamp ' || wher ;

    RAISE INFO '%',sql;

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;

END;

$BODY$

LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

---Calling function

```
SELECT * FROM Function_Test('00:00:00','23:59:59');
```

But getting an error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "00:00:01"
LINE 1: ...ELECT * FROM Test_Timestamp where ColumnA BETWEEN '00:00:01'...
```

Comment: Why a varchar when you need a time? Cast your timestamp to a time datatype and you get the time-part of your timestamp. It looks like you make things way to complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the column to a time: `ColumnA::time`

You should also *not* pass a time (or a date, or a timestamp) as a varchar. And you don't need dynamic SQL or a PL/pgSQL function for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Function_Test(St_Time time, en_Time time)
RETURNS TABLE (columX timestamp)
AS
$BODY$
    SELECT * 
    FROM Test_Timestamp 
    where columna::time between st_time and en_time;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Call it like this:

```
select *
from Function_Test(time '03:00:00', time '21:10:42');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extract to the hour, minute and second

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT